# Given a printing of a monochrome bitmap image, how can I recover the bitmap?

Tags: gimp, image-processing, bitmaps

I have a printout (scan, really) of what was originally a monochrome bitmap image. The pixels are clear enough that I can manually doodle in a reproduction of it in Paint or Gimp or some other image software.

However, this is tedious and seems like something that could be automated. What software can I use to recover the original bitmap? Can this be accomplished within Gimp via scaling and filters? I anticipate having to do many more of these and would prefer a process a little less mind-numbing and alot less slow.

Comment: Try scanning and then converting it to a vector graphic using something like inkscape

Comment: @johnbchron I'm very familiar with the auto-trace functions, including the new centerline tracing. Though they are invaluable tools, they won't be able to recover these... if I scale the image up so that each pixel can be traced, they won't be anywhere near square. And if I leave them unscaled, Inkscape will interpret those as diagonals. In some (but not all) the individual pixels were printed as circles and not squares anyway (dot matrix printers, yay!).

Comment: Could you add a picture in your original post?

Comment: I will be able to edit one in shortly. Please be patient.